# Using PouchDB in an Angular2 Cli Application with SystemJS and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, pouchdb, systemjs, angular2-cli

I've searched through dozens of questions and answers on GitHub and Stack Overflow for the past two days. I haven't found a solution yet. Hopefully someone here can help me!

I have gotten PouchDB working in development mode, using `ng serve` and `ng build`, however, when I try to build for production, using `ng build --prod`, it encounters an error:

> ...
>
> Error: Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle file:///home/josiah/Projects/www/projectname/vendor/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.js. Ensure that this module sits within the baseURL or a wildcard path config.
>
> ...

My current Angular2 Cli generated `system-config.ts` contains:

```
const map: any = {
  'pouchdb': './vendor/pouchdb/dist/',
};
```

and

```
const packages: any = {
   "pouchdb": {
      main: "pouchdb",
      defaultExtension: "js"
   }
};
```

In `angular-cli-build.json` I have added `'pouchdb/dist/*.+(js|js.map)',`.

I am using `PouchDB` in my project with this import: `import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';`

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `./`, like so:

```
const map: any = {
  'pouchdb': 'vendor/pouchdb/dist/',
};
```

Shout out to https://github.com/delasteve who pointed this out to me on https://gitter.im/angular/angular-cli.